# Symfony2: ACL - Using findAcls()

Tags: php, symfony, acl

I am having a problem with attempting to batch load ACLs for a specific object (in the example below it is the Account class.)

If I am using the following code, even though acl_object_identities is populated, the returning array that should be populated is empty. What am I missing?

```
        $oids = array();
    foreach ($accounts as $account) {
        $oid = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($account);
        $oids[] = $oid;
    }

    $aclProvider->findAcls($oids);
```

$accounts holds the array of entities found with a findAll().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like the ACLs are pulled after all with the key being an iterative follow-up to see what permissions are in place.

```
foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    if ($securityContext->isGranted('EDIT', $account)) {
        // Granted, do something with it
    } else {
        // Not Granted
    }
}
```

So, it seems that everything is working a designed.